# HEVC, HTML5 video and not breaking older devices

Tags: html, video

```
<video muted preload autoplay loop playsinline class="background">
    <source src="{{path '/video/background_hevc.mp4'}}" type="video/mp4; codecs=hevc,hvc1" />
    <source src="{{path '/video/background.mp4'}}" />
    <source src="{{path '/video/background.webm'}}" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

So I have the above video block. Works fine in the current version of everything, so I was testing everything -1 version and I discover that it doesn't play at all in iOS 10.x or below.

What should happen is it should try and play the first and fail so move to the second.

What is happening is it tries to play the first and can't and stops.

If I reorder the sources, sure it'll work, but then nothing plays the HEVC version (which is much smaller/more efficient) which means I needn't have bothered.

Has anyone hit this issue before? Does anyone have a solution that doesn't involve a bunch of shitty Javascript? ;)

Comment: Note: the `<source>` tag does not use or need a closing slash.

Comment: Just my IDE autocompleting :)

Comment: Get a better IDE.

Comment: you'll probably need to use some javascript - `var vid = document.createElement('video');
isSupp=vid.canPlayType("video/mp4;codecs=hevc");` though support right now is afaik still very limited